# Pandas unable to parse csv with multiple lines within a cell

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file Decoded.csv

```
Query,Doc,article_id,data_source
5000,how to get rid of serve burn acne,1 Rose water and sandalwood: Make a paste of rose water and sandalwood and gently apply it on your acne scars.
2 Leave the paste on your skin overnight then wash it with cold water the next morning. 
3 Do this regularly together with other natural treatments for acne scars to get rid of the scars as quickly as possible.,459,random
5001,what is hypospadia,A birth defect of the male urethra.,409,dummy
5002,difference between alimentary canal and accessory organs,The alimentary canal is the tube going from the mouth to the anus. The accessory organs are the organs located along that canal which produce enzymes to aid the digestion process.,461,nytimes
```

And there are 3 Query 5000,5001 & 5002.
Query 5000 has a Doc value which has multiple lines and that is confusing for pandas. 
(1 Rose water and sandalwood: Make a paste of rose water and sandalwood and gently apply it on your acne scars.
2 Leave the paste on your skin overnight then wash it with cold water the next morning. 
3 Do this regularly together with other natural treatments for acne scars to get rid of the scars as quickly as possible)

My python code is as under

```
def main():
    import pandas as pd
    dataframe = pd.read_csv("Decoded.csv")
    queries, docs = dataframe['Query'], dataframe['Doc']
    for idx in range(len(queries)):
        print("idx: ", idx, " ", queries[idx], " <-> ", docs[idx])
        query_doc_appended = (queries[idx] + " " + docs[idx])
    print(query_doc_appended)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And it fails. Please point me how to get rid of new line characters so that Query 5000 has the complete set of statements for Doc.

Comment: any error messages? what does your datafile look like? unclear.

Comment: Data file is provided in the question itself Decoded.csv
,Query,Doc,article_id,data_source...And
error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 53, in <module>
    main()
 line 49, in main
    query_doc_appended = (queries[idx] + " " + docs[idx])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
idx:  0   how to get rid of serve burn acne  <->  1 Rose water and sandalwood: Make a paste of rose water and sandalwood and gently apply it on your acne scars.
idx:  1   nan  <->  nan

Comment: and what error messages do you get when you run this program?

Answer (score 0):

your Query 5001 row has too many fields in it, making it have 5 columns instead of the 4 that the other rows have.

```
5001,what is hypospadia,A birth defect of the male urethra.,409,dummy
```

you can double-quote your Doc content within Decoded.csv to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

- to allow multiline fields, the field data has to be enclosed in double quotes.
- there are also comma's in your field data.

So, the csv should look like this:

```
Query,Doc,article_id,data_source
5000,"how to get rid of serve burn acne,1 Rose water and sandalwood: Make a paste of rose water and sandalwood and gently apply it on your acne scars.
2 Leave the paste on your skin overnight then wash it with cold water the next morning. 
3 Do this regularly together with other natural treatments for acne scars to get rid of the scars as quickly as possible.",459,random
5001,"what is hypospadia,A birth defect of the male urethra.",409,dummy
5002,"difference between alimentary canal and accessory organs,The alimentary canal is the tube going from the mouth to the anus. The accessory organs are the organs located along that canal which produce enzymes to aid the digestion process.",461,nytimes
```

In case there are double quotes inside those fields, they have to be escaped with another double quote.